# List.js Filtering Results

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I'm using list.js (http://listjs.com/) to create a filter from a dropdown.

```
<div id="viewList">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
<form id="filter">
    <select id ="gname" name="gname">
        <option value="0">css</option>
        <option value="1">tf2</option>
        <option value="2" >teamspeak3</option>
        <option value="3" >csgo</option>
        <option value="3" >gmod</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="sloc" name="sloc">
        <option value="0">US</option>
        <option value="1" >EU</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button id="filter-results" type="button">Filter Results</button>
<table width="891" align="center" cellspacing='0'>
<thead> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->
    <tr>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="sname" width="350" >Server Name</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="gname" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">Game</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="sloc" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">Loc</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="ipadd" width="204">IP Address</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="numply" width="91">Players</th>
        <th width="258">Map</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- Table Header -->
<tbody class="list">
    <tr>
        <td class='sname'>[GFLClan.com]Minigames :: FastDL, Store, and more!</td>
        <td class='gname'><a title='css'><img src='Flags/css.png'/></a></td>
        <td class='sloc'><img src='Country/US.png'/></td>
        <td class='ipadd'>74.91.119.32:27015</td>
        <td class='numply'>14/40</td>
        <td class='mapn'>mg_ski_mountain_dev</td>
        <td><a href='steam://connect/74.91.119.32:27015' title='Join!'><img src='button/join.gif'/>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td class='sname'>[GFLClan.com] *MarioKart* 2+3 | Instant Respawn | No Lag</td>
        <td class='gname'><a title='tf2'><img src='Flags/tf2.png'/></a></td>
        <td class='sloc'><img src='Country/US.png'/></td>
        <td class='ipadd'>74.91.115.139:27015</td>
        <td class='numply'>15/32</td>
        <td class='mapn'>dm_mariokart2_b3</td>
        <td><a href='steam://connect/74.91.115.139:27015' title='Join!'><img src='button/join.gif'/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Using this javascript

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'sname', 'gname', 'sloc', 'ipadd', 'numply', 'mapn' ]
};

var featureList = new List('viewList', options);

$('#filter-results').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        var gname = $("#gname").text();
        var sloc = $("#sloc").text();
        if (item.values().gname == gname && item.values().sloc == sloc) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
```

The filter doesn't work. What I want to do is for users to use drop down menu to show only results they need. So if they select css and US, it should only show gname tds with 'css' in and sloc tds with 'US' in. I don't know if the reason it doesn't work is because I am using images in gname and sloc classes. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
$("#gname").text();
```

you should be using

```
$("#gname option:selected").text();
```